# Android Button Text Color Animation

Tags: android, button, textcolor

I have a button. I want to create a color animation for button text.
How can I do it? How can ı use ObjectAnimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use;

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(button, "textColor",getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            colorAnim.setDuration(1000);
            colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            colorAnim.start();
```